# How to convert a MediaWiki installation using MySQL to SQLite?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, sqlite, convert, conversion

We're running a small own MediaWiki installation based on MySQL here. For simplicity reasons it would be great to convert this installation to an SQLite variant as it then would not require a separate data base instance.

What I'm looking for is a way of how to accomplish this. One idea would be that we could create an XML dump of the data somehow and reinsert it later again. But MediaWiki claims that such dump would not cover the complete data: We'd use user accounts, edit logs and other stuff.

Has anyone any experience in doing such a conversion? What do you think would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mysql2sqlite.sh script on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh)

write the script like this,

```
./mysql2sqlite.sh myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

If you want to know other ways to convert, [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite)